# Magento 2 what is use of knockout.js?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, knockoutjs

I am new to Magento 2. Need help to understand the concept of the knockout.js.

Why Magento 2 has used knockout.js?  I did try to understand it and did check this useful articles:

[How knockout.js works](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/knockout-js-in-magento-2/)

But still not getting anyhint why it has been implemented in Magento and what's the use of it?

Please help me to understand the concept of the knockout.js.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Magento 2 uses the `Knockout.js` framework to **dynamically build some parts of it's frontend**. It provides a great way to create interactive frontend data bound components within your Magento 2 store. `Knockout.js` eases working with dynamic javascript user interfaces by making use of the **`Model-View-ViewModel`** (MVVM) pattern.

**Features of Knockout.js**

- Observables and dependency tracking
- Declarative bindings
- Templating

**Observables** means that you define data models in javascript that you pick for example via ajax. You than 'connect' these models with elements in a template. Does anything change in your data model than the user interface is updated automatically. This can also work the other way around. With dependency tracking we can setup chains of relationships between model and data, to transform and combine it.

With **declarative binding**, we can manipulate more properties of the UI instead of just showing values. Depending on our data model we can change visibility, text, html, css, styles, attributes, ...

Over at [learn.knockoutjs.com](http://learn.knockoutjs.com) they have a real nice web app set up that takes you through the basics of using `Knockout.js` in a 'hands-on' style. It's really fun to work through.

**`Knockout.js` is very similar to `Angularjs`**. But Angularjs is a very complete and large framework with dependency injection, ajax, routing, cookies and much more ... Probably **Magento 2 was just looking only for a way to do data-binding**.

**An example of customizing the minicart**

If you want to write html template structures in Magento that work with `Knockout.js` you have to deal with regular **.html** files in addition to the traditional **.phtml** files. **These templates are loaded via ajax.** You can usually find these files in 
    app/code///view/frontend/web/template/

or in

```
app/design/frontend/<theme-vendor>/<theme>/<module-vendor>_<module>/web/template/.
```

**So they are inside the template folder inside the web folder and not in the regular templates folder.**

To modify the minicart we must copy the file `app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html` to our theme folder. So we copy the file to `app/design/frontend/<your-theme-vendor>/<your-theme>/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html`

Inside this template file we can use al sorts of code structures like an 'if' structure for example. Say we want to hide elements when the cart is empty, we can add the following around a code block.

```
<!-- ko if: cart().summary_count == 0 -->
    <div>some code</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Using the syntax with comments like this is called 'containerless control flow syntax'. We could also bind this to the container itself of course. Like so:

```
<div data-bind="if: cart().summary_count == 0">some code</div>
```

Similar to the if binding there is also the foreach binding.

```
<!-- ko foreach: someArray --><!-- /ko -->
```

We can also add text that can be translated.

```
<span class="notice"><!-- ko i18n: 'All prices are tax included.' --><!-- /ko --></span>
```

Calling another template can be done with the template binding.

```
<!-- ko template: 'path/to/template' --><!-- /ko -->
```

The part that initially loads the content form the minicart in the header comes from a regular .phtml file, that can be found `app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml` Here we also see some `knockout.js` bindings.

For instance we can change the code that shows the counter next to the cart icon **from:**

```
<!-- ko if: cart().summary_count -->
    <!-- ko text: cart().summary_count --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

**to:**

```
<!-- ko if: cart().summary_count == 1 -->
    <!-- ko i18n: 'item' --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: cart().summary_count != 1 -->
    <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Now the counter also shows up when there are actually zero items in the cart. And it shows '0 items'.

Source: studioemma

Comment: Very helpful answer Mr.patel.  appreciate your help.  One question "why you have written: "ko i18n:"  in comment?   is it necessary?  what is use of it and what it does?

Comment: `ko i18n` is used to display a translation of the text when you have multistore with multiple languages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  also,  what is use of  following code "cart().summary_count == 1"  and "ko template: "  in comment? how do i know about all values?

Comment: @jack, `<!-- ko -->` is not comment, actually it's a knockout js code. `<!-- ko if: cart().summary_count == 1 -->` means it's check if cart summary is equal 1 it's go to in condition and print text `item`.

Comment: Quite brief and helpful