# ko syntax in Magento2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

How to pass option value dynamically in Magento 2 using ko.

**web/template/minicart/item/default.html**

I want the loop

```
for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
 <option>i</option>}
```

But I can able to pass only static value in option

```
<select data-bind="attr: {
                             id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                            'data-cart-item': item_id,
                            'data-item-qty': qty,
                            'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                             }, value: qty">                        
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>                      
                        </select>
```

How to do this?If anyone knows that please explain me

Comment: How to find corresponding js file for this template...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an array and use it in the data-bind.

Please see an example : http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

Please check given below URLs to understand the concept of the knockout.js

[Magento 2 what is use of knockout.js?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187817/magento-2-what-is-use-of-knockout-js)

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html